# How to install a plugin in symfony 1.4 with or without PEAR?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, pear

I know it is not good question to ask, but I don't find any satisfactory answer from Google that we able to install plugin in symfony 1.4 with or without PEAR.

If yes then why? and if no then how do we install it manually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a quick search on Google, [one result](http://pramodsivadas.co.in/2011/11/symfony-install-plugin-manually/) shows you how to install a plugin manually, without PEAR (which I recommend):

1. Download the plugin from the symfony site.
2. unzip the file and if the folder has version number, remove that.
3. Copy the plugin to the `projectpath/plugins`
4. Edit `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` to add

   ```
   $this->enablePlugins('pluginName');
   ```
5. Run `symfony plugin:publish-assets` in the command line.